# Generate text in loop and order number

Tags: jquery, loops

I have a dive which is getting shown on click. When you click on the add person button it clone and add the .loop div.

What I need is there is a heading text in that loop div (person 1), I need this text to be updated for each loop. For example person1,person 2, person 3 ...

Here is my code and **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8JQrj/4/)**

```
$(function () {
    clicks = 0;
    $('div.test').on('click', function () {
        $('.attnd2').show();
        $('div.loop').show();
        if ($('div.loop').length < 5) {
            clicks++;
            if (clicks > 1) {
                newLoopDiv = $($('div.loop')[0]).clone().appendTo(".container");
                $('input', newLoopDiv).each(function (index, element) {
                    $(element).attr('name', $(element).attr('name') + clicks);
                });
            } else {
                newLoopDiv = $($('div.loop')[0]).appendTo(".container");
                $('input', newLoopDiv).each(function (index, element) {
                    $(element).attr('name', $(element).attr('name') + clicks);
                });
            }
        }
        $(".remove").click(function () {
            $(this).closest('.loop').remove();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: please make sure your indentation is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8JQrj/15/)

**HTML:** (note the `#loops` and no content at all):

```
<div class='container' id="loops"></div>
<div class="test">Add person</div>
```

**CSS:** (No `display:none;` for `.loop` needed)

**JS/jQ:**

```
var c = 0;

function HTMLloop(c) {
    return '<div class="loop">\
              <strong>Person ' + c + '</strong><br/> \
              <input type="text" name="firstName' + c + '"/> \
              <input type="text" name="lastName' + c + '"/> \
              <input type="text" name="mail' + c + '"/> \
              <input type="text" name="company' + c + '"/> \
           </div>';
}

$('.test').on('click', function () {
    if (c<5) $('#loops').append( HTMLloop(++c) );
});
```

<sub>**...yep, that's it.**</sub>

Comment: You dont want it this way. This way the names are `name1` and `name12` and `name13`

Comment: @Martijn oh really? **I don't think so.** You should inspect the code and attributes in console.

Comment: the original input has `name1`, adding `+clicks` will add the increment after it. Unless im missing something

Comment: @Martijn you're probably missing something :)

Comment: @Martijn The question wasnt even about name it was about changing the text in the `<strong>` tag

Comment: And i've found it. Maybe update your answer to clearify you changed the names? Easy to miss heheh

Comment: @DGS if we find some mistakes in the code (that were not spotted originally by the OP) and we fix it in our answer, it makes our answer even more valuable ;)

Comment: @Martijn What are you talking about? the OP's demo has no `name1` etc. Take a closer look... http://jsfiddle.net/8JQrj/4/

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yeah that's fine but down-voting an answer based on it not fixing a problem not relevant to the problem is not good

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I was saying your answer was correct from the start. I was trying to point out that Martinjn was bringing up issues with the names that were not relevant to the question.

Comment: Thank u it works but Y it is adding 2 set of divs when remove button is added for each div? PLs check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8JQrj/16/

Comment: Sowmya that's cause you did **not** read my **notes**. You're cloning multiple `class` elements. What I said about using `.class`? As you can see to prevent such issues I used `$new = $('.loop:first')` but you use just `$('.model_loop')` I'll erase my first answer cause looks like will bring you just headaches...

Comment: @Sowmya additionally why you use a click function inside a click function? Is there any reason? Do it like: http://jsfiddle.net/8JQrj/18/

Comment: @Sowmya Additionally now having the remove button you'll need to update all the names (a function that will loop all your elements) and do a `c--` on `.remove` click

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan this fiddle whic youhave given in comment is fine but when youremove a div set it should rename the person number to it's current order,that is what i am not gettng. And also add person button should work to add divs evn after removing the divs..

Comment: In short, if user accidentally remove all the 5 divs, he should be again ableto add it by clicking on the Add person button.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36314/discussion-between-sowmya-and-roko-c-buljan)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the name in strong:

```
// I prefer this for readability
$(newLoopDiv).find('strong')[0].html( 'Person '+ clicks );
// but this is more dynamic
$(newLoopDiv).find('strong')[0].html( $(element).find('strong')[0].replace("1", clicks) );
```

And to update all the input names (because those are wrong, check your source:

```
// In your loop with the inputs:
$(element)[0].name = $(element)[0].name.replace("1", clicks);
```

---

If you give your inputs a name like an array, its allot easier:

```
<input name="example[]" value="this is the first" />
/* then you click */
<input name="example[]" value="this is the 2nd" />
/* then you click */
<input name="example[]" value="this is the 3rd" />
```

After a submit, it will be something like this:

```
example{
    [0] = "this is the first",
    [1] = "this is the 2nd",
    [2] = "this is the 3rd"
}
```

Accessable with a foreach loop:

```
foreach($_POST['example'] as $key =>$value){
    echo $value;
    echo '<br />';
    echo $_POST['otherinputName'][ $key ] ;
}
```

This has another benefit, if you were to `.remove()` the 2nd on, no recounting is needed. The $_POST value simply gets a value less, only having 'this is the first' and 'this is the 3rd' without you having gaps in your increment to fix

Comment: input is generating name attr in order. What I need here is to change the static text which is in <strong> tag.

Comment: Updated my answer with more info

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
newLoopDiv = $($('div.loop')[0]).appendTo(".container");
            $(newLoopDiv).children('strong').text("Person "+clicks);//Add this Line
            $('input', newLoopDiv).each(function (index, element) {
                $(element).attr('name', $(element).attr('name') + clicks);                    
            });
```

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8JQrj/9/)

Comment: You dont want this. You are updating the `strong` element each litteration of the loop (so 10 inputs means it updates the strong 10 times)

Comment: Out of the loop = better. You always want loops to do as little as possible :)